# Display Prestashop new product field on product-list.tpl and home featured modules

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Using this tutorial on this page [Adding new tabs and fields to Prestashop products’ back office](http://nemops.com/prestashop-products-new-tabs-fields/), I was able to add a new field for author for products in my Prestashop. I was also able to display it on product page by adding Product.php to override/classes/ and inserting this code below:

```
class Product extends ProductCore
{
/** @var string Custom Product Field */
    public $custom_field;
}
```

I then added {$product->custom_field} to product.tpl to display the new field. My challenge is that the same code does not work when added to product-list.tpl and the homefeatured.tpl module files.
Can any one explain how to achieve this? I am not an expert but I can find my way around tutorials if I have one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the function used by the module Homefeatured to get the products and edit the SQL request in this function to add your new field.

You can't display your new propertie because the SQL request don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Use . instead of ->

In product-list.tpl & homefeatured.tpl $procuct is array not object.

And do not miss the getFields() method in Product class:

```
public function getFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getFields();
    $fields['custom_field'] = $this->custom_field;
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: After making this correction adding {$product.custom_field} to the tpl files and the code above to the module php file, I got an error message that Notice: Undefined index:custom_field in ....product-list.tpl. The same error shows in the homefeatured module.

Comment: Are you sure that you have actual value in this field in the database? If it's possible the field to not have value, you should use {if $product.custom_field}{$product.custom_field}{/if}

Comment: Even after adding {if $product.custom_field}{$product.custom_field}{/if}, the problem is still appearing. Is there another way to this, maybe by using new hook?

Comment: Are you sure that you have actual value in this field in the database?

Comment: Please help me take a look at the full code in the tutorial. I have checked the database and the information I added inside the fields in the backend are saved to the ps_product_lang table. I am not a programmer so I do not know what else to check.